# Pandas aggregating several columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I need to aggregate several columns by one column. I have the following code that works but for now column and I am struggling to modify it to several columns.

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'Group': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
    'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'Qty': [100, 202, 403, 754, 855, 1256]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
result = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([', '.join(map(str, x))])).reset_index()
print(result)
```

This produces a table with the column "Group" (the groupby) and one column for "Value", but I need another column with the aggregate output for the variable Qty. Actually, my dataset has 12 variables that I need to aggregate.
Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance and Happy 2024!!

Comment: Have you heard of pandas' built-in `df.groupby(...).agg(...)` function? Read its docs here: [DataFrameGroupBy.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

Comment: `df.astype(str).groupby('Group', as_index=False).agg(', '.join)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it with many columns and in a more practical way, loop over all columns that are not "Group", this would give you practicality if you have a lot of variables:

```
aggregated_data = df.groupby('Group').agg({col: concatenate_with_comma for col in df.columns if col != 'Group'})
```

As for the usage of the `concatenate_with_coma`, here it is:

```
def concatenate_with_comma(series):
    return ', '.join(map(str, series))
```

FYI you can use "sum" and other functions instead, if this is your goal eventually. The result is like this:

```
         Value             Qty
Group                         
A      1, 2, 5   100, 202, 855
B      3, 4, 6  403, 754, 1256
```